# VB.Net sample for Google APIs Client Library for .NET

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm just getting started on a project to replace Google Map's depreciated dynamic KML support.

I'm think Fusion Tables is the way to go. I have data that is updated daily - a map with several regions and I need to update the Color column with a daily forecast.

We currently have a six day's of forecast HTML w/KML sent to our site. In my new scheme I'm thinking I will still have six web pages but they will point to six Fusion Tables. Daily (almost, weekends excluded) we'll run the code to update the color values on the Fusion Tables.

Here's our current site: http://slocleanair.org/air/AirForcasting_map3.php  The page displays the next day forecast at the top of the page.

My normal toolset is VS 2013 Express and VB.Net.

I found the Google APIs Client Library for .NET project page and downloaded the binaries for the API. The sample link is currently throwing a 403 access error but my guess is the project is C# and overly complex and not for Fusion Tables. So I was wondering if someone can point me to/post a VB.Net sample for updating Fusion Tables from VB.Net?